# Using methods on Generics

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I have a ton of methods like this:

```
public UIPCompanyButton AddCompanyButton (string name, Company company, UIEventListener.VoidDelegate methodToCall, GameObject contents)
{
    return UIPCompanyButton.Create (name, company, methodToCall, contents);
}
```

that I'd like to replace with a single method like this:

```
    public T AddButton<T,K>(string name, K item, UIEventListener.VoidDelegate methodToCall, GameObject contents) where T:UIPMenuButton
{
    return T.Create(name, item, methodToCall, contents);
}
```

which obviously doesn't work at the T.Create part. Is there a certain syntax I need to do this?

I'm also open to a different method with the same result: a single method that takes in a derived menuButton and creates the right one with the right class of "item".

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget, if you feel one of the answers below helped you resolve your problem or answered your question the best, accept one by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't call static methods on generic types - not without reflection. Aside from anything else, there's no way of constraining a generic type to have specific static members. The closest to that is the parameterless constructor constraint.

Comment: correction: Yeah, I'd want to send in two generic types... or ideally derive the second by checking the class of the first. it just seems that since all my buttons have the exact same create method (except the "item"), and are derived from the same base class, there shouldn't be a need to copy paste dozens of these almost-identical AddItemButton methods.

Comment: @LZG: Well there's nothing in C# to help you do this in a type safe way. You can use reflection if you like, or factories - but generics aren't going to help you.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a factory to create your objects. Here is a small working example. It might not be the *best* way to implement a factory pattern, but it should get you going.

For a more in depth example and explanation, see [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328373/Understanding-and-Implementing-Abstract-Factory-Pa).

```
public class Button {
    public string Whatever { get; set; }

    public Button() {
        Whatever = "Hello, world!";
    }
}

public interface IAddButton {

    Button CreateButton();
}

public class ClassToMakeButtonFor1 {

    public static void RegisterMe() {
        ButtonFactory.Register(typeof(ClassToMakeButtonFor1), new ButtonFactory1());
    }
}

public class ButtonFactory1 : IAddButton {

    public Button CreateButton() {
        return new Button();
    }
}

public class ClassToMakeButtonFor2 {

    public static void RegisterMe() {
        ButtonFactory.Register(typeof(ClassToMakeButtonFor2), new ButtonFactory2());
    }
}

public class ButtonFactory2 : IAddButton {

    public Button CreateButton() {
        var b = new Button { Whatever = "Goodbye!" };
        return b;
    }
}

public static class ButtonFactory {
    private static Dictionary<Type, IAddButton> FactoryMap = new Dictionary<Type, IAddButton>();

    public static void Register(Type type, IAddButton factoryClass) {
        FactoryMap[type] = factoryClass;
    }

    public static Button MakeMeAButton<T>() where T : class {
        return FactoryMap[typeof(T)].CreateButton();
    }
}

internal class Program {

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        ClassToMakeButtonFor1.RegisterMe();
        ClassToMakeButtonFor2.RegisterMe();

        Button b = ButtonFactory.MakeMeAButton<ClassToMakeButtonFor1>();
        Console.WriteLine(b.Whatever);

        b = ButtonFactory.MakeMeAButton<ClassToMakeButtonFor2>();
        Console.WriteLine(b.Whatever);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could consider is to have some interface (e.g. ICreator) that defines a Create method you want to call.

Then you would constrain your type parameter to types that implement the interface ( where T : ICreator).

Then you would call the method on an instance, not a static method. So in your case maybe you could call item.Create(...).

Makes any sense for your case?

Comment: well the problem is the Create method creates the instance, so i cant really create an instance before I call Create. If I could just get the class of T, I could call that specific create method, but I can't seem to figure out what class T is. Then I could just throw it to some switch statement like "case T is UIPCompanyButton:" or something.

Comment: Could you put the Create method in the class Company (or K in your other code sample)? Those instances you do already have. This is what I meant by item.Create. This item is something that you already have, as you get it as a parameter.

Comment: If you really, really want to get the class of some object, you can use GetType() method, but creating a switch like that is not very object-oriented, and seems like a thing that would lead to bad style and bad maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be able to make your Button class generic. Depending on how much logic lives in each of these derived classes, this may not work for you.

```
class Button<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }

    public Button(string name, T item, ...)
    {
        // Constructor code
    }
}

// Helper class for creation
static class Button
{
    public static Button<T> Create<T>(string name, T item, ...)
    {
        return new Button<T>(name, item, ...);
    }
}
```

Then, to use this:

```
Button<Company> button = Button.Create("Name", company, ...);
```